# Flastlist: detect click outside of item

Tags: react-native

I'm working on a chat app that display new messages once you click on the screen (not on 1 item of the list)

So far, I have this:

```js
<View
  style={styles.viewContainer}
  {..._panResponder.current.panHandlers}
>
  <FlatList
    ref={ref => chatRef.current = ref}
    style={styles.viewContainer}
    data={messages}
    renderItem={renderItem}
    onContentSizeChange={() => chatRef.current.scrollToEnd({animated: true})}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
  />
</View>
```

The click is working, but I can no longer scroll on my `Flastlist`.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: _panResponder value

```js
 const _panResponder = React.useRef(
    PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
      onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => false,
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => true,

      onPanResponderGrant: (evt, gestureState) => {
        shouldDisplayNextMessage.current = true;
      },
      onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {
        if (shouldDisplayNextMessage.current) {
          shouldDisplayNextMessage.current = false;
        }
      },
      onPanResponderTerminationRequest: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onPanResponderRelease: (evt, gestureState) => {
        if (shouldDisplayNextMessage.current) {
          setMessagesIndex(prevValue => prevValue + 1);
        }
      },
    }));
```

Comment: Can you just add some screenshots or Gif to be clear for us

Answer (score 0):

I agree the gesture responder lifecyle is confusing. Dit you check out [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.60/gesture-responder-system) documentation page, and more specifically the part on [capturing](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.60/gesture-responder-system#capture-shouldset-handlers)?

> Before the responder system bubbles up from the deepest component, it will do a capture phase, firing on*ShouldSetResponderCapture. So if a parent View wants to prevent the child from becoming responder on a touch start, it should have a onStartShouldSetResponderCapture handler which returns true.

So in this case I guess your `onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture` should also return false, otherwise the parent view will prevent the flatlist from becoming a responder when scrolling.

I think it is best to copy the documentation of these negotiation methods into your code.

Comment: I tried that, but with the same result. Weird stuff: if I set every `ShouldSet` to false, the scroll is still not working

Comment: And it's working without the panresponder, right? Just checking.

Comment: Yes, without the PanResponder, it's working, but I still miss the click to display new items